# Como ordenar un array de objetos con librería lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

Estoy intentando ordenar un un array de objetos con base al [algoritmo de Johnson](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Johnson), me recomendaron una librería muy buena que se llama [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash), la probé en un arreglo convencional y funcionó perfectamente, el problema es que necesito implementar esa instrucción en un Arreglo de objetos y no funciona nada, sé que esta funcionando la librería pero en teoría no hace nada.

Tal vez esta mal mi lógica o hay algo de la librería que debería saber, les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

El siguiente código es desarrollado en javascript y jquery, arriba de la función únicamente está una tabla en html donde obtengo los datos mediante un ID

Mi tabla:

```
  <table id="example1" width="100"
                    height="10" class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
                    <thead >
                    <tr >
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th>Lote</th>
                      <th>OSTHM</th>
                      <th>FTHM</th>
                      <th>DTHM</th>
                      <th>CFTHM</th>
                      <th>DLTHM</th>
                      <th>LBTHM</th>
                      <th>NTHM</th>
                      <th>RMTHM</th>
                      <th>E1THM</th>
                      <th>E2THM</th>
                      <th>LTHM</th>
                      <th>C2THM</th>
                      <th>C3THM</th>
                      <th>EKTHM</th>
                      <th>M1THM</th>
                      <th>M2THM</th>
                      <th>CA1THM</th>
                      <th>CA2THM</th>
                      <th>EFTHM</th>

                      

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      @foreach($ruta as $r)
                      <tr  >
                        <td>{{$r->idr}}</td>
                        <td name="nombre" id="nombre">{{$r->productos->nombre}}</td>
                        <td><input class='form-control' type="number" id="txt-cant"></td>
                        <td name="OSTHM" id="OSTHM">{{$r->OSTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="FTHM" id="FTHM">{{$r->FTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="DTHM" id="DTHM">{{$r->DTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="CFTHM" id="CFTHM">{{$r->CFTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="DLTHM" id="DLTHM">{{$r->DLTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="LBTHM" id="LBTHM">{{$r->LBTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="NTHM" id="NTHM">{{$r->NTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="RMTHM" id="RMTHM">{{$r->RMTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="E1THM" id="E1THM">{{$r->E1THM}}</td>
                        <td name="E2THM" id="E2THM">{{$r->E2THM}}</td>
                        <td name="LTHM" id="LTHM">{{$r->LTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="C2THM" id="C2THM">{{$r->C2THM}}</td>
                        <td name="C3THM" id="C3THM">{{$r->C3THM}}</td>
                        <td name="EKTHM" id="EKTHM">{{$r->EKTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="M1THM" id="M1THM">{{$r->M1THM}}</td>
                        <td name="M2THM" id="M2THM">{{$r->M2THM}}</td>
                        <td name="CA1THM" id="CA1THM">{{$r->CA1THM}}</td>
                        <td name="CA2THM" id="CA2THM">{{$r->CA2THM}}</td>
                        <td name="EFTHM" id="EFTHM">{{$r->EFTHM}}</td>
                        
                      
                        
                          </td>

                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

Función:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#analisis').click(function(){
      obtenerDatosTabla();
        
      
    });
    });

    
    function obtenerDatosTabla(){

      document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML +=''


    $('#example1 tr').map(function(){
    let nombre=$(this).find('#nombre').eq(0).text(); 
    let cantidad=$(this).find('#txt-cant').val();
    let maq1=$(this).find('#OSTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq2=$(this).find('#FTHM').eq(0).text();          
    let maq3=$(this).find('#DTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq4=$(this).find('#CFTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq5=$(this).find('#DLTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq6=$(this).find('#LBTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq7=$(this).find('#NTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq8=$(this).find('#RMTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq9=$(this).find('#E1THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq10=$(this).find('#E2THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq11=$(this).find('#LTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq12=$(this).find('#C2THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq13=$(this).find('#C3THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq14=$(this).find('#EKTHM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq15=$(this).find('#M1THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq16=$(this).find('#M2THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq17=$(this).find('#CA1THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq18=$(this).find('#CA2THM').eq(0).text(); 
    let maq19=$(this).find('#EFTHM').eq(0).text(); 


    
    var multi=(2*maq1);
    var F1=multi+parseFloat(maq2)+parseFloat(maq3)+parseFloat(maq4)+parseFloat(maq5)+parseFloat(maq6)+
    parseFloat(maq7)+parseFloat(maq8)+parseFloat(maq9)+parseFloat(maq10)+parseFloat(maq11)+parseFloat(maq12)+
    parseFloat(maq13)+parseFloat(maq14)+parseFloat(maq15)+parseFloat(maq16)+parseFloat(maq17)+parseFloat(maq18);
    var multi2=(2*maq19);
    var F2=parseFloat(maq2)+parseFloat(maq3)+parseFloat(maq4)+parseFloat(maq5)+parseFloat(maq6)+
    parseFloat(maq7)+parseFloat(maq8)+parseFloat(maq9)+parseFloat(maq10)+parseFloat(maq11)+parseFloat(maq12)+
    parseFloat(maq13)+parseFloat(maq14)+parseFloat(maq15)+parseFloat(maq16)+parseFloat(maq17)+parseFloat(maq18)+multi2;


    function Maquina1(){
      this.nombre=nombre;
      this.F1=F1;
      this.M1=M1;
    }

    
    function Maquina2(){
      this.nombre=nombre;
      this.F2=F2;
      this. M2=M2;
    }
    
    var M1= "Máquina 1";
    var M2= "Máquina 2"
    
    if(F1<=F2){
    for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {  
    var ORDER= new Maquina1(nombre,M1,F1);
    
    }
   }else{
    if(F2<=F1){
    for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {  
    var ORDER= new Maquina2(nombre,M2,F2);
    }
   }

}
console.log(_.orderBy (ORDER ,  [ 'M1', 'F1','F2'] ,  [ 'asc','asc',','desc' ]));
    });
    }
    </script>
```

Lo que obtengo:

[image: resultados obtenidos]

Lo que esperaría:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta se centra en ordenar. ¿Podrías por favor incluir en tu pregunta el contenido de los objetos  a ordenar? El código que adjuntas es irrelevante porque ni siquiera adjuntas las tablas y no se sabe el tipo de datos con el que estás trabajando ni su estructura. Adjunta un ejemplo de la estructura del objeto que quieres ordenar, y el resultado final de cómo esperas que quede ordenado.

Comment: SI, sorry ya lo corregi espero sea más claro